# Django filter() Increases Result QuerySet Rather than Reducing

Tags: python, django

In testing my Django application I ran across a performance issue with a particular query when a particular filter() was used.  The issue was solved, but I don't understand why.

I'm filtering a QuerySet based on 3 criteria.  When including them all at once, I get the expected number of results.  When moving one of the clauses to its own filter() call, the resulting QuerySet is much, much larger than it should be and is filled with seemingly duplicate entries.

See below for an illustration of this.  Moving the `result__is_false=False` clause to its own filter() causes a huge expansion in the resulting QuerySet.

```
>>> Finding.objects.filter(project=1, result__scan_session__is_enabled=True,\ 
    result__is_false=False).count()
3566

>>> Finding.objects.filter(project=1, result__scan_session__is_enabled=True)\
    .filter(result__is_false=False).count()
10050380
```

The problem was that I needed to conditionally apply the filter in question, not every time.  I solved the problem by converting the filter() routine to an exclude() routine like this:

```
>>> Finding.objects.filter(project=1, result__scan_session__is_enabled=True)\
    .exclude(result__is_false=True).count()
3566
```

That seemed to have done the trick!

While I'm happy that this worked, I don't understand two things:

1) Why posts explaining filter() and exclude() seem to suggest that they can be treated as equal but opposite, when based on the example above, that is not always the case.

2) Why moving the `result__is_false=False` clause to its own filter() caused the huge jump in results in the first place.

Does anyone have any insight into either of these?

Comment: print the queries with `print(Finding.objects.filter(...).query)` and all will be answered

Comment: The second part (explaining what the problem was) should probably be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these look like the expected result of how successive `filter` calls work on multivalued relationships. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) explain in detail, with examples:

> Everything inside a single filter() call is applied simultaneously to
>   filter out items matching all those requirements. Successive filter()
>   calls further restrict the set of objects, but for multi-valued
>   relations, they apply to any object linked to the primary model, not
>   necessarily those objects that were selected by an earlier filter()
>   call.

So your second `filter` call returns any `Finding` where there's at least one non-false result. The `exclude` call returns any finding where there's not at least one false result. They're interchangeable when querying non-nullable fields on single values, but not in all cases.

Comment: Thanks Peter!  I had read that page a while back but it didn't really click that it was applicable to my situation until you pointed it out.  Now to go back through my code and re-evaluate subsequent filter() calls and possibly change to exclude().